Eigenvalues of A, B, and (A+B)
Could the following statement be correct? If all the real parts of the eigenvalues of matrices A and B are negative, then all the eigenvalues of (A+B) also have negative real parts. Alternatively, the equivalent form of the problem could be: If all the eigenvalues of matrices A and B have positive real parts, then all the eigenvalues of (A+B) also have positive real parts. I have not been able to find a counterexample. However, a mathematical proof should be absolute, not relative

Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

For instance, you could add some context as: Where did this question come from, or did you make it up on your own? If so, what made you think of it? If you haven't come up with any counter-examples, presumably you've come up with a number of confirming instances. Can you provide those?

Thank you for your guidance Brian Tung. I’ve been focusing on the design of observers for non-linear systems for a while now. If my understanding of the problem is accurate, I can demonstrate the stability of the observer. The reason I posed the question was to determine if this particular issue has been previously identified and proven in any references. Unfortunately, I haven’t found any such information.

Don't post that information in a comment. Edit your question to improve it. Users shouldn't have to read the comments to get the context.

Note again: Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning. ¶ (I guess I'll have to start bolding this since no one reads that far anymore.)

Here is a counterexample: all the eigenvalues of
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \tag{1}
$$
have positive real parts, but
$$
A+B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}
$$
has a zero eigenvalue.

I appreciate your help.
